# How to make git send an email in case of unresolved merge

Tags: git

I use git to share config files between several computers. So I've set up a small script that does a bunch of `git pull` / `git push` each time one of these computers is started or halted.

The problem is that I don't always take the time to read the output of these scripts, and so I could miss some merging conflicts warnings.

Is there a way to make git send me an email each time a `git pull` from a repository leads to unresolved conflicts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the example hook (in .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample (the first one, that uncomments "Conflict" messages)) to find conflict messages and send them in email.

http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: If I understand correctly, this hook is only called by `git commit`, and the code in the example is run if this commit is a merge and it is succesful. But what I would like is a hook that would be run in case a `git pull` leads to unresolved conflicts...

Comment: Rereading, I think you're right.  There may not be a hook run on unsuccessful pulls.  Why not look at the exit status of git pull, in that case?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I think I'll use something like : `git pull 2> /tmp/git_pull_output.txt; if [ $? != 0 ]; then mail -s "Git pull failed" foo@example.com < /tmp/git_pull_output.txt; fi`